# ADO connection from Excel to SQL Server executes but returns no records

Tags: sql-server, excel, ado

I have a spreadsheet from which I want to pass SQL script to my SQL server Database, both to retrieve records and run stored procedures.

Here's my code:

```vb
Sub ApendPickListData()
Dim SqlConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim listID As Integer
Dim lists As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLstr As String

SqlConn.ConnectionString = "Provider = 'SQLOLEDB';Server=MyServer\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Uid=Username;PWD=Password;"
SqlConn.Open

 

 'The following execution of a stored procedure works
    SqlConn.Execute "Exec spListsInsertNew @Type = 'Picking', @Date ='" & Date & "'"
    
SQLstr = "SELECT ItemList.ItemNumber from ItemList"
    'This method doesn't work
    
With lists
    .ActiveConnection = SqlConn
    .Source = SQLstr
    .Open
    Debug.Print .RecordCount
    'prints -1 in the immediate window - no records
End With

'Neither does this method
Set lists = SqlConn.Execute(SQLstr)
Debug.Print lists.RecordCount
'prints -1 in the immediate window - no records    

SqlConn.Close

End Sub
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I've searched this site and others, found examples where this code should work.  I've tested the select statement in SSMS and it works as expected.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you properly parametrise your query, does it work?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how do you properly parameterize a select query with no parameters?

Comment: `Exec spListsInsertNew @Type = 'Picking', @Date ='" & Date & "'"` Has 2 parameters, of which one you are injecting.

Comment: For your latter query you don't execute the query, you just assign it to a variable (`SQLstr`)

Comment: That line of code was the one that worked - see the comment above it.  It's the select statement into a record set that doesn't work.  I put the sp execution in there to show that the connection string is viable.

Comment: After assigning it to the variable, I ran
`lists.source = SQLstr`
then opened it.
I also tried the sqlconn.execute method.  Should that not have executed the query?

Comment: `RecordCount` is not reliable right after opening a recordset with a default cursor. There are a few methods but the one I used to use the most is `.MoveLast` then `.MoveFirst` then `.RecordCount` and begin processing records. I believe you can also fix it by setting a client side cursor with something like `.CursorLocation = <some constant>`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `lists.movefirst lists.movelast` and the movelast throws a run-time error automation error

Comment: Try setting `.CursorLocation = adUseClient` before opening the recordset.

Comment: That did it. I will post the code that worked as answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked was from Mark Balhoff's comment.  Here it is:

```
Sub ApendPickListData()
Dim SqlConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim listID As Integer
Dim lists As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLstr As String

SqlConn.ConnectionString = "Provider = 'SQLOLEDB';Server=Myserver\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB;Uid=Username;PWD=Password;"
SqlConn.Open


SQLstr = "select dbo.ItemList.ItemNumber from dbo.ItemList"

With lists
.ActiveConnection = SqlConn
.Source = SQLstr
.CursorLocation = adUseClient 'This was the key!
.Open
Debug.Print .RecordCount

End With

SqlConn.close
End Sub
```